# How to autoformat code on array initialization?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, indentation, code-formatting

Every time I have array initialization and try to format the code by pressing `CTRL+K` and `CTRL+D`, the code indent doesn't get formatted automatically.

Sample code.

```
var users = new[]
{
    new User(),
    new User (     ),
       new User { Id = 1 },
    new User {     Id = 1 }   ,
            new     User { Id = 1 }   ,
    new    User { Id = 1      },
};
```

Expected result.

```
var users = new[]
{
    new User(),
    new User(),
    new User { Id = 1 },
    new User { Id = 1 },
    new User { Id = 1 },
    new User { Id = 1 },
};
```

My indenting setting.

[image: Setting]

Already tried installing [Code Maid](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496) and pressing shortcut in the following menu (Format Document, Format Selection).

[image: Menu]

Comment: try ctrl +e, d. On some copies of visual studio, that is somehow the default instead.

Comment: @pquest, still doesn't work, is there any patch that I can download to fix it?

Comment: not that I am aware of. This is kind of lame, but removing and the replacing the semicolon at the end will probably fix it.

Comment: @pquest, still not working

Comment: If you go to Edit|Advanced|Format Document, what's the keyboard shortcut it lists?

Comment: @Hammerstein, I edited the question, and already tried both of them too

Comment: Do you have some invalid syntax somewhere else? It's the only other thing I can think of that stops formatting.

Comment: No, it compiled successfully, does it work on your visual studio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your block of code and use `CTRL+E` , `\` which deletes horizontal white space.  Then tabify the code as desired.

You can also find this under `EDIT` --> `ADVANCED` --> `Delete horizontal white space` from your Visual Studio menu.

Comment: hmmmm I needed to press the shortcut one by one on each white space

Comment: @YuliamChandra it works for me when I select the whole block.

Answer (score -1):

#### Check out this [CodeMaid -Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496/) for Visual studio.

Comment: already installed and pressed `CTRL+M` and `Space`, but it's still not working

Answer (score -1):

Highlight that section of the text and try to press `CTRL+K+F` or `CTRL+K`, `CTRL+F`